# Liquid Templates: How to do counter loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, liquid

This is only to quickly prototype something Adhoc... is it possible to do this in liquid? I just want to iterate over a number I set in the template.

```
for var=i; i<3; i++
```

Comment: This should help: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers#for-loops

Answer (score 1):

Ah, here it is:

```
  {% for i in (1..4) %}
    {{ i }}
  {% endfor %}

 # results in 1,2,3,4
```